# wp_query maximum limit without pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress, limit

My client has a custom post type called 'Clients'. She uses this to record all information about each client she has. She then sometimes leaves these in either draft mode or published. She would like to be able to see all of her clients at a glance and copy and paste all of their details straight from the web page on a regular basis. I have created the following query (note the query is only showing fist and last name at the moment for testing):

```
        <?php
        $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'clients',
            'post_status' => array('draft', 'publish'),
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                $fname = get_field('fname');
                $sname = get_field('sname');

                echo '<p>'.$fname.', '.$sname.'</p>';
            endwhile;
        ?>
```

However, this returns no results. When I change the 'posts_per_page' to a number, the query works. However, if this number is above 58 no results are returned again. I think somewhere there is a limit to how much can be output in 1 query. I cannot use pagination at the minute as the client is admit she'd want to see all information on one page. Is there another way of querying this without limits? Or a way to adjust the limit?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have just tried upping the limits in my php file to:
`max_execution_time = 60`
`max_input_time = 120` 
`memory_limit = 64M`

I can now see all results, however I feel that this is not the ideal solution. If anyone knows of a more stable solution it would be appreciated. I don't really want to have to keep upping server limits every time we get too many.

Comment: 64 doesn't sound excessive to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was down to my local setup, as soon as it was uploaded to the clients server the error disappeared. Sorry I forgot to close the question

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to debug it directly I'm not sure *why* you're seeing this issue.  Alternatively you can try using the `'nopaging' => true` option instead of the `'posts_per_page'` option.  Does that method behave?

Comment: Thanks for that. For some reason adding
    "no_paging" => true

Doesn't give all results but allows me to go as high as 124 before it returns no results. When leaving the "posts_per_page" out it changes to the default of 10, when setting it to -1 no results are returned.

Comment: Could this be more related to my local server settings than the WP_Query itself?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the custom post type name is `clients` and not `client`? That is the only thing that I can point, as I the only parameter that is *custom* by the developer ^^.